# Split string in python and remove terminal " character

Tags: python, string, list, split

**Background:**

I have a string `SourceString` which is comma separated floating numbers returned by an instrument. Printing it shows this:

`"364.3889926095051E-3,15.0529859951886E+3,29.5266606165309E+3,148.7897394963915E+3,1.0681575514441E+6"`

Next, in order to extract individual floating numbers, I convert it to a list using this code:
`Readback_list=SourceString.split(",")`

Printing `Readback_list` displays the resultant list as:

`['"364.3889926095051E-3', '15.0529859951886E+3', '29.5266606165309E+3', '148.7897394963915E+3', '1.0681575514441E+6"\n']`

**Question:**

When I print individual elements of this list, I see that the first and last elements have a `"` in the output shown in **attached** photo.

- How to remove the `"` from these elements?
- I am unsure why is split() not getting rid of the `"` by itself.

[image]

Comment: Use `strip('"')` before splitting

Comment: `SourceString.strip('"')` makes no change to `SourceString`. I still get the same output: `"364.3889926095051E-3,15.0529859951886E+3,29.5266606165309E+3,148.7897394963915E+3,1.0669996574743E+6"`

Comment: `Readback_list = SourceString.strip('"').split(",")` -- didn't work?

Comment: it works when I added the split. Sorry I misunderstood your initial suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon, it does strip " from the beginning, but not from the end. With `Readback_list = SourceString.strip('"').split(",")` I see this output:  `['15.0529859951886E+3', '29.5266606165309E+3', '148.7897394963915E+3', '1.0675786044592E+6"\n']`